# V4l2 video streaming on Arch with RPi2

Tags: camera, archlinux, pi-2, raspicam, v4l2

I'm running an intentionally minimal Arch OS on my RPi2 (installed via `ArchLinuxARM-rpi-2-latest.tar.gz` dated `2015-08-14`), and I'm trying to have it stream video from the camera. I followed the [camera instructions on the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Raspberry_Pi#Raspberry_Pi_camera_module), including appending

```
gpu_mem=128
start_file=start_x.elf
fixup_file=fixup_x.dat
```

to `/boot/config.txt`, and putting

```
bcm2835-v4l2
```

in `/etc/modules-load.d/rpi-camera.conf`. The camera itself seems to work fine using `/opt/vc/bin/raspistill` and `/opt/vc/bin/raspivid`, but when I attempt to stream video via:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-width 1920 --v4l2-height 1080 --v4l2-chroma h264 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:12345}'
```

I get the error

```
v4l2 demux error: cannot open device '/dev/video0': Permission denied
```

Ok, so I check the permissions on `/dev/video0` and see that it's readable by the `video` group, so I add my user to this group and now when I run the `cvlc` command I don't get the error, but I can't see the stream on a remote computer either. When I turn on the v4l2 overlay (`v4l2-ctl --overlay=1`) before running the `cvlc` command, I can indeed see that the camera is working, but still no visible stream on the remote computer. I used `vlc` to try to receive the stream and get the error

```
core stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
```

Any suggestions for how to trouble-shoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with cvlc, but on Linux there are a few checks you can do from the command line on both/either the RPi with the camera, and a client to see if the daemon is running, listening and if connection to the daemon's port can be made.

The following all assume that the `cvlc` daemin is listening on port 12345 as in your question above.

On the RPi with the camera, to check if `cvlc` daemon is listening on (TCP) port 12345 (the `-o` arch just limits output so you do not have to look at as much output):

```
$ sudo ss -tlpn -o '( sport = 12345 }'
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                 Local Address:Port                                Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      1                                  *:12345                                          *:*                   users:(("cvlc",pid=24275,fd=3))
```

On either another host, which has netcat (nc) installed (OS X usually does) you can check simple connectivity with the following:

```
$ nc -z -v 192.168.1.2 12345
Connection to 192.168.1.2 12345 port [tcp/italk] succeeded!
```

*Note: if your version of netcat (nc) complains about the `-v` flag, just omit it, and you can check the return value from the command for success or failure. The verbose output is just a nice convenience for this test.*

Hopefully this can help a bit debugging either end of the connection.